# How to properly encrypt and decrypt large block of data using bouncycastle AES-GCM

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, aes-gcm

So I am trying to create a software that can encrypt and decrypt a large file, but when I tried to do that with a large file, it gives me `mac check in GCM failed` at the end of the decryption phrase but when I decrypt a smaller file, it works normally fine.

I also tried to find some information online but most of them doesn't seem to help.

Here is the last attempt on the code after many retries:

```
static int CycleSize = 1024 * 1024 * 100;
static int Encrypt(byte[] PasswordToKey,string OpenPath, string SavePath)
        {
            // Generate a random Nonce
            byte[] nonce = new byte[128 / 8];
            new Random().NextBytes(nonce);
            // Setup the Crypto Engine
            GcmBlockCipher cipher = new GcmBlockCipher(new AesEngine());
            cipher.Init(true, new AeadParameters(new KeyParameter(PasswordToKey), 128, nonce));
            // Read the file ad start the encryption
            using (FileStream plainfile = new FileStream(OpenPath, FileMode.Open))
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[CycleSize];
                plainfile.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                int bytesRead = plainfile.Read(buffer, 0, CycleSize);
                int TotalFileSize = nonce.Length;
                using (FileStream encryptfile = new FileStream(SavePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                {
                    encryptfile.Write(nonce, 0, nonce.Length);
                    int CycleCount = 0;
                    byte[] cipherText = new byte[0];
                    int len = 0;
                    while (bytesRead > 0)
                    {
                        CycleCount = CycleCount + 1;
                        if (bytesRead < CycleSize)
                            encryptfile.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
                        else
                            encryptfile.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Current);
                        cipherText = new byte[cipher.GetOutputSize(bytesRead)];
                        len = cipher.ProcessBytes(buffer, 0, bytesRead, cipherText, 0);
                        Console.WriteLine("Cycle #" + CycleCount + "'s Data Length: " + cipherText.Length);
                        TotalFileSize = TotalFileSize + cipherText.Length;
                        bytesRead = plainfile.Read(buffer, 0, CycleSize);
                        if (bytesRead > 0)
                            encryptfile.Write(cipherText, 0, cipherText.Length);
                    }
                    cipher.DoFinal(cipherText, len);
                    encryptfile.Write(cipherText, 0, cipherText.Length);
                    Console.WriteLine("Cycle Completed, Final Size: "+TotalFileSize);
                    Array.Clear(buffer, 0, buffer.Length); // Clean the memory so that it stops hogging the memory if you decided to keep it running after it finishes the task.
                }
                return TotalFileSize;
            }
        }
static public int Decrypt(byte[] PasswordToKey, string OpenPath, string SavePath)
        {
            using (FileStream encryptfile = File.OpenRead(OpenPath))
            {
                // Setup the Crypto Engine
                byte[] nonce = new byte[16];
                encryptfile.Read(nonce, 0, nonce.Length);
                encryptfile.Seek(16, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                GcmBlockCipher cipher = new GcmBlockCipher(new AesEngine());
                cipher.Init(false, new AeadParameters(new KeyParameter(PasswordToKey), 128, nonce));
                byte[] buffer = new byte[CycleSize];
                int bytesRead = encryptfile.Read(buffer, 0, CycleSize);
                int TotalFileSize = nonce.Length + bytesRead;
                using (FileStream plainfile = new FileStream(SavePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                {
                    int CycleCount = 0;
                    int len = 0;
                    byte[] cipherText = new byte[0];
                    while (bytesRead > 0)
                    {
                        CycleCount = CycleCount + 1;
                        cipherText = new byte[cipher.GetOutputSize(bytesRead)];

                        len = cipher.ProcessBytes(buffer, 0, bytesRead, cipherText, 0);
                        Console.WriteLine("Cycle #" + CycleCount + "'s Data Length: " + cipherText.Length);
                        TotalFileSize = TotalFileSize + cipherText.Length;
                        bytesRead = encryptfile.Read(buffer, 0, CycleSize);
                        if(bytesRead > 0)
                            plainfile.Write(cipherText, 0, cipherText.Length);
                    }
                    cipher.DoFinal(cipherText, len);
                    plainfile.Write(cipherText, 0, cipherText.Length);
                    Console.WriteLine("Cycle Completed, Final Size: " + TotalFileSize);
                    Array.Clear(buffer, 0, buffer.Length); // Clean the memory so that it stops hogging the memory if you decided to keep it running after it finishes the task.
                }
                return TotalFileSize;
            }
```

Comment: This code is extremely confusing. Why are you using `Seek()`? Why are your buffers so large?

Comment: You ignore the return values of `ProcessBytes` and `DoFinal` and instead always write out the entire `cipherText` array. That is a bug. I would recommend you start over. You can write both of those functions in less than half as many lines with much greater clarity and with much less of a memory footprint.

Comment: If I write out the entire `cipherText` array, wouldn't big files takes up large amount of memory?